# How to use the ChannelFactory

Tags: c#, wcf, proxy

Basically I have the code from [MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734681.aspx)

The code is:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

// This code generated by svcutil.exe.
[ServiceContract()]
interface IMath
{
     [OperationContract()]
     double Add(double A, double B);
}

public class Math : IMath
{
public double Add(double A, double B) 
{
    return A + B;
}
}

public sealed class Test
{
    static void Main()
   {
       // Code not shown.
   }

public void Run()
{
    // This code is written by an application developer.
    // Create a channel factory.
    BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();

    EndpointAddress myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/MathService/Ep1");

    ChannelFactory<IMath> myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMath>(myBinding, myEndpoint);

    // Create a channel.
    IMath wcfClient1 = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
    double s = wcfClient1.Add(3, 39);
    Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
((IClientChannel)wcfClient1).Close();

    // Create another channel.
    IMath wcfClient2 = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
    s = wcfClient2.Add(15, 27);
    Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
((IClientChannel)wcfClient2).Close();
myChannelFactory.Close();
}
}
```

However based on my superficial understanding, it is a self host WCF. The above code is combining service code and client code together.
If the WCF is host in a server, we don't know its internal struture at all. Then how to consume it in client side?
I used the code

```
ChannelFactory<IMath> myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMath>(myBinding, myEndpoint);
```

But intellisense doesn't know **IMath** at all.
I am not strong on proxy, ChannelFactory etc. Now my question is that if the service IMath is host at http://www.someserver/IMath.svc, how to write code in client side to consume it?

Please don't think adding web reference to the clent...

**updated**:
In the service wsdl:
I have something like:

```
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_iMath" type="tns:iMath">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" /> 
 - <wsdl:operation name="Add">
 <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/iMath/add" style="document" /> 
 - <wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal" /> 
 </wsdl:input>
- <wsdl:output>
 <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
- <wsdl:operation name="LoadUnbillsFromOrion">
  <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/iMath/LoadUnbillsFromOrion" style="document" /> 
- <wsdl:input>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:input>
- <wsdl:output>
   <soap:body use="literal" /> 
   </wsdl:output>
   </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
 - <wsdl:service name="Math">
 - <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_iMath" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_iMath">
   <soap:address location="http://wsvc01/Imath.svc" /> 
  </wsdl:port>
 </wsdl:service>
```

Comment: IMath and its implementation goes into its own assembly and you reference that assembly from your client.

Comment: I don't see any code to host the service. What you have is a pure client code with unwanted **implementation** of the interface but the implementation is nowhere used.

Comment: Sorry for my ignoance, I don't understand it. I just updated my code. There is no endpoint at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, all you need to know is a binding and endpoint address on your client side.

To consume a WCF service you need to create a proxy.  Unless you specifically need a reason to the ChannelFactory, it's probably easier to create a "Client" class that inherits from [ClientBase<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576141.aspx).

```
public class Client : ClientBase<IMath>
{
    private static Binding MyBinding { get; set; }

    private static EndpointAddress MyEndpoint { get; set; }

    public Client() : base(MyBinding, MyEndpoint)
    {
    }

    public double Add(double a, double b)
    {
        Open();
        var c = Channel.Add(a, b);
        Close();

        return c;
    }
}
```

You then create an instance of your proxy suppling it an endpoint and binding in the constructor (or have the proxy automatically do it in it's default, you can do whatever you want) to communicate with your WCF Service.  You then just Open and Close your client object and then Call your Client.IMathOperation to perform an operation on the service.  The ClientBase<> will handle Channel creation, disposing, pooling etc.

```
Client proxy = new Client();
proxy.Add(1, 2);
```

You'll probably want to put in various wrapper and helper classes on the Client side to handle exceptions, testing your connection before trying to access it, encapsulating opening and closing channels etc. to make it less verbose to use on the client-side.

Comment: Updated with some very basic implementation.  You'll need to get the binding and endpoint from somewhere, either from in-code via static variable that you set at some point during your initialization or via a config file or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I don't have an endpoint(maybe I am wrong but I haven't found it). I only have a soap address, please see my updated wsdl.

Comment: Check out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114139/WCF-The-Right-Way-A-Quick-Reference-Guide it's a really good beginning-to-end tutorial for setting up and using WCF the right way.  Like the other guy said, form what you've shown you don't have any service actually being hosted.  As part of the WCF Configuration you'll create your service bindings and endpoints (among other things).  You'll need those to connect to the service.

Comment: The other guy created the service, the web configuration doesn't have endpoint at all. It is an urgent task, I don't have time to study the material. Can we add the http address to the reference?

Comment: Yes if you know the http address then you can create the [EndpointAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.endpointaddress.aspx) from that.  He probably used the BasicHttpBinding, if you can't find that either.

Comment: Yes,after get endpoint from url, should I use channelfactory or other skills?

Comment: That depends on your specific situation and is something you need to decide.  My opinion is it would probably be easiest to use ClientBase<>.

Comment: The question is that Imath is not recoginzed by intellsense. Should I copy the interface to my side? I don't think so, because it is a black box.

Comment: Can we just add service reference then type the url?

Comment: You need to add a reference to your IMath binary in your client project, yes.  Ideally you'd have a seperate binary for all of you're service contracts.  Look at the link I posted early and read up on it.  You can also add a service reference but then you are just using the Visual Studio templates to auto-generate a bunch of code (like the client/proxy code, it will duplicate any DataContracts etc.).  Depending on the scope of what you're doing it might be the easiest route to go or give you a lot of problems.

Comment: I just tried it, I added the service reference. Then I don't consider endpoint and ClientBase anymore, I just create a instance, is it right? Thank you very much.

Comment: Correct, the "Add Service Reference..." process will automatically detect that information, all you need to do is instantiate the proxies it generates.